# Where to put the "such that", given multiple quantifier

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Personally, I would put the "such that" (i.e. the symbol $:$ or $|$) behind any quantification. That is given an assertion $A(x,y)$, I'd write
$$
\forall x\in X\exists y\in Y:A(x,y)\\
\exists x\in X\forall y\in Y:A(x,y)
$$
However, the lecturer giving the first graders course I'm tutoring writes
$$
\exists x\in X:\forall y\in Y A(x,y)
$$
in the second case (and the same as me in the first case), wich looks "wrong" to me. However, googling didn't produce any source that talks about placement of "such that" at all, so the question is: is there any rule or guideline where to put the "such that", and if so, what is it?

Comment: If the formula is prenexified, it only makes sense to put it after all quantifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking at the colon (:), it is just a convenient delimiter for readability. You could also have written equivalently:

$\exists x\in X:\forall y\in Y : A(x,y)$.

Or you could leave them out entirely:

$\exists x\in X\space \forall y\in Y\space A(x,y)$.

Answer (score 3):

The "such that" is not required by the syntax of first-order logic.

The official syntax is :

> $\forall x \exists y (x < y)$

which is an example of : $\forall x \exists y A(x,y)$.

The "such that" (i.e. the symbol ":" or "|") is used with the [set builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) :

> $\{ x : \varphi(x) \}$ or $\{ x | \varphi(x) \}$

meaning : "the set of objects in the domain of discourse **such that** $\varphi$ holds of".

---

But the issue is with the "good" translation into natural language of the above formulae.

With :

> $∀x∃yA(x,y)$

the natural reading is :

> "for all $x$, there is an $y$ **such that** ..."

while for

> $∃x∀yA(x,y)$

it "sounds better" :

> "there is an $x$ **such that**, for all $y$ ...".

Comment: Yeah, i noticed the absence of $:$ in literature about logic, although the notation seems to be heavily used in papers and lecture notes in different fields. So it seems there's no real right and wrong here...

Comment: @roman - we can say that it is used in your examples as a "punctuation mark", for an easier reading of the formulae.

Comment: Yeah, I get that point of view. Although, after finally figuring out what prenexified means, I think I agree more with GitGuts point of view. I.e. seeing the $:$ as a seperator of the string of quantifiers and the quantifier free part in a prenex normal form, instead of a literal "such that".

Comment: @roman - I understand ... but this is exactly why I've said that the symbol in the offical syntax is unnecessary; we have already parentheses to separate the prefix from the subformula which is the scope of the quantifiers, like : $\forall x \exists y ((x < y) \rightarrow (x \le y+1))$.

Comment: Well, it's as unnecessary as using it as a literal translation of "such that" ;) And since it's not part of the official syntax, it all boils down to personal opinion... Anyway, I think you gave a sufficient answer which I might very well accept in the near future.

Comment: (-1). Firstly, there is no "official syntax." Rather, there is a "standard syntax." More importantly, your answer doesn't deal with the notational problem at hand. The issue is not the notation $\exists x \varphi$ and $\forall x \varphi$. Rather, it is the notation $\forall x \in X \varphi$ and $\exists x \in X \varphi$. And there is no standard notation here; some write a separating colon for both, others just for existence; I have even seen $\forall (x \in X) \varphi$ and $\exists(x \in X) \varphi,$ which is probably what I prefer.

Comment: @goblin - perhaps you do not know that $∀x \in X \varphi$ is only an **abbreviation** for $∀x (x \in X \rightarrow \varphi)$; so, the problem is in any case what is the "use" of the colon after the quantifier : it is only an issue of "readibility" or it affect the menaing of the formula ?

Answer (score 0):

'Such that' typically introduces a restriction or condition that in many statements we do not want.

If we say 'for all $x$ in $S$, property $P$ holds', we are saying something different than if we say, 'for all $x$ in $S$ such that property $P$ holds,...'.

In the former case we are saying that $P$ holds for all $x\in S$. In the latter case we are saying we are looking at those $x\in S$ for which $P$ holds (which may or may not be all $x$ in $S$.